# Bootstrap: Tab content does not show up correctly after using Bootstrap Admin Template

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, tabs

I'm new to HTML and CSS while trying to use the following table https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/tables.html  in my tab-content which does not show up correctly. As other tab-content goes below my Tab 2 tab-content.

This tab was working fine when I was not using sb-admin-2 table in it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="tabs-container">
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
         <li><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
         <li><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
         <li><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
         
    <div class="tab-content">   
        
            <!-- Tab 1 Content -->
            <div role="tabpanel" id="tab-1" class="tab-pane active">
                    <h1>Red</h1>
                    <p>red red red red red red</p>
                </div>  
            <!-- End of Tab 1 Content -->       

                    <!-- Tab 2 Content -->
                            <div role="tabpanel" id="tab-2" class="tab-pane">
                              <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                                  <div class = "card-body">
                                    
                                      <div id="dataTable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper dt-bootstrap4">                                   
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                              <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover dataTable display" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" role="grid" aria-describedby="dataTable_info" style="width: 100%;">
                                                
                                                  <thead>
                                                    <tr role="row">                                        
                                                      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Start date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 100px;">Date</th>
                                                      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Age: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 50px;">Name</th>                                                                        
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </thead>                                                    
                                                  
                                                  <tfoot>
                                                    <tr><th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Date</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Name</th></tr>
                                                  </tfoot> 

                                                  <tbody>
                                                    <tr><td>19-12-2000</t><td>Chris</td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td>03-06-2014</td?<td>John</td></tr>
                                                  </tbody>                                    
                                                </table>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>                                        
                                          </div>
                                        </div>    
                                      </div>
                                    
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div> 
                            </div> 
                            <!-- End of Tab 2 Content Tables -->

            <!-- Tab 3 Content -->
            <div role="tabpanel" id="tab-3" class="tab-pane active">
                    <h1>Yellow</h1>
                    <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
                </div>  
            <!-- End of Tab 3 Content -->



  <script src="https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/js/demo/datatables-demo.js"></script>
      
</body>
</html>
```

Above is the code in my body section. Could you please help me to figure out what is going wrong?

Help is much appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I use your code for the correction.

> You are not adding .nav-item class in .li tag.

Some closing tags issues in table code. Here, is some closing tags issue. Re-view your code.

> **In .tbody tag**
>
> In first .td tag you forget "d" in closing .td tag.   In second .td
> tag you put "?" in-place of ">".

So, these small mistakes creates a problem in your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1">Tab-1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2">Tab-2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-3">Tab-3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
  
    <div id="tab-1" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>Tab-1</h3>
      <h1>Red</h1>
                    <p>red red red red red red</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="tab-2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Tab-2</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover dataTable display" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" role="grid" aria-describedby="dataTable_info" style="width: 100%;">
                                                
                                                  <thead>
                                                    <tr role="row">                                        
                                                      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Start date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 100px;">Date</th>
                                                      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Age: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 50px;">Name</th>                                                                        
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </thead>                                                    
                                                  
                                                  <tfoot>
                                                    <tr><th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Date</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Name</th></tr>
                                                  </tfoot> 

                                                  <tbody>
                                                    <tr><td>19-12-2000</td><td>Chris</td></tr>
                                                    <tr><td>03-06-2014</td><td>John</td></tr>
                                                  </tbody>                                    
                                                </table>
    </div>
    
    <div id="tab-3" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Tab-3</h3>
       <h1>Yellow</h1>
         <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add Scripts to the document. For Bootstrap to work, you will need bootstrap css and Jquery.

1. Add JQuery link to your head

<
script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">

2. Add Bootstrap min js to bottom of the page:

   <
   script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <
   /script>

Comment: I'm still getting the same error after including above link.